# Turn off cores in multicore processor

Tags: windows-7, multi-core

I have several home grown applications that run together, exchange data, and are time synchronized with each other.   I've found that having the OS bouncing around between cores fouls up this synchronization because each core has its own clock reference which is different from core to core.   I am on an HPz230 desktop running 32bit Win7.   I cannot get into the bios with any Fkey combination that I am familiar with.   I've found that any changes I make from msconfig only lasts for the session.   I need the settings to persist.  On a previous Dell I did this from BIOS.   Anyone know how to get into this bios.   I don't know what chipset it is.

Answer (score 0):

According to [HP](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=46157&docId=emr_na-c03101724&docLocale=en_US), it should be either <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: Thanks,  I've pressed every Fkey during bootup and get a very dos looking text menu with 4 selections,  Memory test, two other things that I don't care about and Exit.   I'll play some more with it.